# Align two chart areas windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I have a windows forms application that displays a chart compose by two chart areas, one for price/dates and the second displays volume/price, both should get the same amount of datapoints to draw in each chart area, the issue I have at the moment is that both charts  are not aligned vertically so they are not very clear for the user, I added the following properties to volumen chart area:

```
volumeChartArea.AlignWithChartArea = CHART_AREA_PRICES;
volumeChartArea.AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;
volumeChartArea.AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical;
```

But they still don't look correct, what could it be the solution to fix this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this maybe?

```
if (this.chrtMain.ChartAreas.Count > 0)
  {
    ca.AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical;
    ca.AlignWithChartArea = this.chrtMain.ChartAreas[0].Name;
  }
```

All chart areas will be aligned as they are added this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have done this step but it wasn't working before, then I realized that some code was overwriting this setting messing  it up, nice answer :), cheers!!