# Add two charts below each other using windows chart form

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I can easily create two separate charts but I want to add them in one single chart. one on top and another below it. So How can I do that?

Here is the code that I have tried so far but it only draws one chart on top.

```
// Chart chart1 = new Chart();
            Chart chart1 = new Chart()
            {
                Width = 500,
                Height = 1000
            };


            chart1.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea() { Name = "ChartArea0" };
            //Remove X-axis grid lines
            chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            //Remove Y-axis grid lines
            chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            //Chart Area Back Color

            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

            chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.SeaGreen;

            // Set title.
            chart1.Titles.Add(" GIS");

            // Add series.
            for (int i = 0; i < seriesEXpArray.Length; i++)
            {
                // Add series.
                Series series = chart1.Series.Add(seriesEXpArray[i]);
                series.ChartArea= "ChartArea0";
                // Add point.
                series.Points.Add(ExppointsArray[i]);
            }

             chartArea = new ChartArea() { Name = "ChartArea1" };
            //Remove X-axis grid lines
            chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            //Remove Y-axis grid lines
            chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            //Chart Area Back Color

            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

            // Add series.
            for (int i = 0; i < seriesUserCommenArray.Length; i++)
            {
                // Add series.
                Series series = chart1.Series.Add(seriesUserCommenArray[i]);
                series.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
                // Add point.
                series.Points.Add(UserCommentpointsArray[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your form isn't large enough to hold the `1000` pixels you set the  `Height` to..

Change it to `500` and observe the two `Series` in their `ChartAreas`..

The second (and third) `ChartArea` is **by default** placed below the first one. And both are sized autmatically to display all the points in all their Series.

When adding a fourth `ChartArea` the layout automatically changes to a 2x2 grid.

If you want to override the default arrangement of the `ChartAreas` you can do so by setting their `Positions`. See [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042419/how-to-draw-four-or-more-workareas-horizontally/27046961?s=5|0.3945#27046961)!

Btw: To get rid of the `MajorGrid` lines it is cleaner imo to write:

```
chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

etc..

Also you can simplify the creation of `ChartAreas` and also `Series` like this:

```
ChartArea chartArea1 = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
..
Series series1 = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
..
```

Finally: You do realize that you are adding **numerous** `Series` each with only **one** `DataPoint`? This is rather unusual..