# Dynamically add ChartAreas to Chart in a column and make Chart auto-scrollable in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I need your advice. I want to add many ChartAreas to my Chart and align them vertically in one column which would be 100% width of its parent and which would become scrollable when more chat areas are added.
For now, I use this code to add more chart areas:

```
private void AddChartArea(int index)
{
    string chartAreaName = index.ToString();
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartAreaName);
    chart.Series.Add(new Series());
    chart.Series[index].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart.Series[index].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;
    chart.Series[index].ChartArea = chartAreaName;

    /* Trying to align chart areas vertically */
    chart.ChartAreas[index].AlignWithChartArea = chart.ChartAreas[index - 1].Name;
    chart.ChartAreas[index].AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.AxesView;
    chart.ChartAreas[index].AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical;
}
```

But my chart areas are still going this way when chart areas number is > 3:
[image]

While I want it to be like this but with a vertical scrollbar on the right:
[image]

Comment: Lise [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042419/how-to-draw-four-or-more-workareas-horizontally/27046961#27046961) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as TaW has pointed out, my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042419/how-to-draw-four-or-more-workareas-horizontally/27046961#27046961). But I've made some improvements to automatically adjust overall Chart height.

So my Chart is placed into Panel, which has AutoScroll true.
Then, every time I create a new ChartArea a call this method:

```
private void DrawNewChartArea(int index)
{
    int chartAreaMinHeight = 200;
    chart.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

    float width = 99;
    float height = 100 / chart.ChartAreas.Count;
    float x = 0;
    float y = height * index;

    if (chartAreaMinHeight * (index + 1) > chart.Height)
    {
        chart.Height = chartAreaMinHeight * (index + 1);
        // realign height of all the chart areas if we are changing chart height
        for (int i = 0; i < chart.ChartAreas.Count; i++)
        {
            float caY = height * i;
            chart.ChartAreas[i].Position.Height = height;
            chart.ChartAreas[i].Position.Y = caY;
        }
    }

    chart.ChartAreas[index].Position = new ElementPosition(x, y, width, height);
}
```