# How to position chart areas vertically

Tags: c#

I was creating chartAreas. While adding up to three chart areas, each chart were aligned vertically stacked above on another. But when I added another chart area, it automatically placed the 4 areas in 2X2 position([created chart areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaDZC.png) ).

How can I make the chart area position vertically(chart area in 4X1)?

Comment: Here: [Align two chart areas windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348383/align-two-chart-areas-windows-forms)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align two chart areas windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348383/align-two-chart-areas-windows-forms)